# Clipping and reprojecting in one process for modelbuilder // "Save raster layer as" ... in modelbuilder

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, clip, qgis-modeler

I want to build a model in the QGIS Modelbuilder.
First it should do a clip. Afterwards it should be reprojected (from Geographic WGS84 Coordinates to Gauss-Krüger). I only see one way to do this: with the clip by extent and warp gdal tools. This will produce lots of missing values at the edges, which is quite bad for my application. Although it would work with another clipping, it is kind of complicated to ask for 8 coordinates in 2 different coordinate systems (which couldn't even be simply translated) and kinda circuitous for an automated process.

The "save as" / "save raster layer as" menu (by rightclicking the layer) would be optimal for this task, because it can directly extract in a (re-)projected Coordinate System. Is there any way to use it in the modelbuilder? I guess only by implementing it as an extra module. I can't find its source code, though. Do you know where I can find it?

Did I miss something / is there a better way to do this task?